# Why I get TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a Food delivery program but when I calculator total food python say TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' i try to fix qty int to float but it's not work
I have no idea how to fix it's please help

this is my code

```
while user_input_code != "E" and user_input_code != "D02" and user_input_code != "D01" and user_input_code != "S02":

    if user_input_code != "S01":
        print("Invalid code..")
        print("Please Try again..")

    elif user_input_code == "S01":
        print("This is Search Stores program..")
        print("you want to see store name?")
        user_ask_store = input("Yes or No (Y/N) : ").upper()

        if user_ask_store == "Y":
            show_menu_store_food()
        user_input_store = input("Input your stores number : ")
        while user_input_store != "3" and user_input_store != "2":
            if user_input_store != "1":
                print("Wrong code!!!")
            elif user_input_store == "1":
                show_menu_moo()
                user_ask_food = input("Enter your food number : ")

                if user_ask_food == "1":
                    print("Fried Pork\nFood expenses 69 bath")
                    qty = float(input("How many do you want? : "))
                    user_pay = 69.00
                    user_food_name = "Fried Pork"
                    sum_food = qty * user_pay
                    user_pay_list.append(user_pay)
                    total_food_list.append(user_food_name)
                    qty_list.append(qty)
                    total_food_pay_list.append(sum_food)

                elif user_ask_food == "2":
                    print("Third Heaven Pork\nFood expenses 69 bath")
                    qty = float(input("How many do you want? : "))
                    user_pay = 69.00
                    user_food_name = "Third Heaven Pork"
                    sum_food = qty * user_pay
                    user_pay_list.append(user_pay)
                    total_food_list.append(user_food_name)
                    qty_list.append(qty)
                    total_food_pay_list.append(sum_food)

                elif user_ask_food == "3":
                    print("Sour Pork\nFood expenses 159 bath")
                    qty = float(input("How many do you want? : "))
                    user_pay = 159.00
                    user_food_name = "Sour Pork"
                    sum_food = qty * user_pay
                    user_pay_list.append(user_pay)
                    total_food_list.append(user_food_name)
                    qty_list.append(qty)
                    total_food_pay_list.append(sum_food)

                user_exit_list.append(user_input_code)
            show_menu_store_food()
            user_input_store = input("Are you done?\nif not Please choose stores number : ")
        while user_input_store != "3" and user_input_store != "1":
            if user_input_store != "2":
                print("Wrong code!!!")
            elif user_input_store == "2":
                show_menu_aoy()
                if user_input_store == "2":
                    user_ask_food = input("Enter your food number : ")
                    if user_ask_food == "1":
                        print("Pork In Lime\nFood expenses 56 bath")
                        qty = float(input("How many do you want? : "))
                        user_pay = 56.00
                        user_food_name = "Pork In Lime"
                        sum_food = qty * user_pay
                        user_pay_list.append(user_pay)
                        total_food_list.append(user_food_name)
                        qty_list.append(qty)
                        total_food_pay_list.append(sum_food)

                    if user_ask_food == "2":
                        print("Fried Egg\nFood expenses 48 bath")
                        qty = float(input("How many do you want? : "))
                        user_pay = 48.00
                        user_food_name = "Fried Egg"
                        sum_food = qty * user_pay
                        user_pay_list.append(user_pay)
                        total_food_list.append(user_food_name)
                        qty_list.append(qty)
                        total_food_pay_list.append(sum_food)

            show_menu_store_food()
            user_input_store = input("Are you done?\nif not Please choose store number : ")
            user_exit_list.append(user_input_code)
    print("\t")
    user_input_code = input("Enter code : ").upper()
```

this is how to i calculator

```
tax = total_food_pay_list * 0.07
```

I hope you guy can help me

Comment: what are you expecting tax to be? you have a list and your trying to multiply it by a float. What would you expect that result to be python doenst know how to multiply a list by a floa

Comment: Couldn't your variable `total_food_pay_list` be an integer rather than a list? So you could use the plus-equal operator `=+` instead of appending `sum_food` to it.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
You posted 80 lines of code for a 3-line problem.  You did not describe what you expect as a result, and you did not try to trace the problem values.

Comment: Thanks for your guy's advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot multiply a list (not in this way at least)
if you want to calculate total tax you should do sth like this:

```
tax = sum(total_food_pay_list) * 0.07
print(tax)
```